# Yii Mailer doesn't work

Tags: php, yii

I trying to send mail using yii simple mailer ...

I followed the step :

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-simple-mailer/

And download the extension and put in yii extension folder :

https://github.com/tlikai/YiiMailer

Then put the code to config/main.php:

```
'mailer' => array(
        // for smtp
        'class' => 'ext.mailer.SmtpMailer',
        'server' => 'theserver',
        'port' => '25',
        'username' => 'theadmin',
        'password' => 'thepassword',

        // for php mail
        'class' => 'ext.mailer.PhpMailer',
     ),
```

Then in my controller I wrote this code to send mail:

```
$to = 'wahaha@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Hello Mailer';
$content = 'Some content';

Yii::app()->mailer->send($to, $subject, $content);
```

Then the browser gave me the error :
**Property "PhpMailer.server" is not defined.**

Did I miss something in my code?

Comment: is the extension class added in your config file?

Comment: @nosthertus `'class' => 'ext.mailer.SmtpMailer',` not consider added?

Comment: try `import=>array('ext.mailer.*');` in your config file

Comment: @nosthertus did you mean config/console.php ?

Comment: your config `main.php`

Comment: @nosthertus added but still the same ... anything else ?

Comment: @TheSmile try this link http://yatinmistry.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/yii-framework-send-phpmailer-smtp/

Comment: @YatinMistry so i have to replace all $to,$from,$from_name,$subject,$message? sorry little dont understand

Answer (score 1):

In config/main.php

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
        'Host'=>"localhost",
        'Username'=>'thesmile1019@gmail.com',
        'Password'=>'wakakaka',
        'Mailer'=>'smtp',
        'Port'=>25,
        'SMTPAuth'=>true,
    ),
```

In Component/controller.php

```
public function mailsend($to,$from,$from_name,$subject,$message)
{
    $mail   = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
    $mail->SetFrom($from,$from_name);
    $mail->Subject  = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->AddAddress($to, "");

    // Add CC
    if(!empty($cc)){
        foreach($cc as $email){
            $mail->AddCC($email);
        }
    }

    // Add Attchments
    if(!empty($attachment)){
        foreach($attachment as $attach){
            $mail->AddAttachment($attach);
        }
    }

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        return false; // Fail echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else {
        return true;    // Success
    }
}
```

In controller

```
public function actionSendMail(){
    $token = $_POST['YII_CSRF_TOKEN'];              
    if ($token !== Yii::app()->getRequest()->getCsrfToken()){

        Yii::app()->end();
    }
        $to = 'thesmile1019@gmail.com';
        $from = 'localhost';
        $from_name = 'mface';
        $subject = 'testing';
        $message = 'testing';


if($token == true){
        $util = new Utility();      

        $util->detectMobileBrowser();

        $util->checkWebSiteLanguageInCookies();

        $this->layout = "masterLayout";
        $this->render('mailsend');

        $this->mailsend($to,$from,$from_name,$subject,$message);
}else{

        print_r("Not Sent");
        die();  
}
```

}

**Process not problem going correct but didn't receive the mail**

Comment: You have to call this function from your controller     $this->mailsend($to,$from,$from_name,$subject,$message,$cc,$attachment); not in mailsend. this will go to infinite loop. So remove from here and call from your required controller.

Comment: @YatinMistry yes i put in my controller doesn't work

Comment: @YatinMistry actually i want to do email validation ... user click a submit button then system will auto send a email for them

Comment: @YatinMistry I edited the code ... Browser gave me this message  _RegisterController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "mailTemplate"_

Comment: Change this line  $mail->MsgHTML($this->mailTemplate($message)); to  $mail->MsgHTML($message); This is my custom method which give me common template for all mailer in my application. so you are not required to use this.

Comment: @YatinMistry sorry i very new in yii ... so in my code I declare those $to, $from, $from_name, $subject and $message inside controller is correct ?

Comment: I have created my function "mailsend()" in components/controller.php. so just copy that function in controller.php in and use this call from your actionSendMail() method

Comment: @YatinMistry I edited the code again ... all going correct but I didn't receive the mail ... do u know why ? anything that i missed ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63327/discussion-between-yatin-mistry-and-the-smile).

Answer (score 1):

Change your port in `pathtowebroot/protected/config/main.php`

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
        'class'=>'ext.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
        'Host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
        'Username'=>'thesmile1019@gmail.com',
        'Password'=>'wakakaka',
        'Mailer'=>'smtp',
        'Port'=>465,
        'SMTPAuth'=>true,
        'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl'
    ),
```

Comment: there's not such thing as main/config.php

Comment: @noc2spamツ Typo mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I undo'ed my neg vote. Cheers :)